# R t interval calculation

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

I am studying t-intervals calculation concept and trying to perform the calculations in R.

My issue is that I am performing the calculation through three different methods and I am getting three different results, so I guess I am doing something wrong.

Here are my calculations:
I am using the R `mtcars` dataset and estimating a Linear Model (using R function `lm`) of `mtcars$mpg` as the outcome and `mtcars$wt` (car's weight) as the regressor:

```
data(mtcars)
y <- mtcars$mpg; x <- mtcars$wt; n <- length(y)
se <- sd(y)/sqrt(n) # Standard Error of the Estimation
#now, I calculate the conf interval (ci) using the concept's formula
ci <- mean(x) + c(-1,1)*qt(.975,df=n-1)*se
ci
[1] 1.044304 5.390196
f <- lm(y ~ x)
c <- summary(f)$coefficients
c
             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 37.285126   1.877627 19.857575 8.241799e-19
x           -5.344472   0.559101 -9.559044 1.293959e-10
b0 <- c[1,1] ; b1 <- c[2,1]
yh <- b0 + b1*mean(x)
yh
20.09062
c(yh-ci[1],yh+ci[2])
19.04632 25.48082 #this is my t interval using the concept formula

#Now, the t-interval calculation using R t.test function
t.test(y)
One Sample t-test
data:  y
t = 18.8569, df = 31, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  17.91768 22.26357
sample estimates:
mean of x 
  20.09062 
#So, you can see I get the same estimation of y (20.09...) but a different t-   interval as that calculated before with the formula

#Finally, the t-interval calculated with R predict formula
predict(f, data.frame(x=mean(x)), interval="confidence")
    fit      lwr      upr
1 20.09062 18.99098 21.19027
#and, again, I got the same fit value of y (20.09..) but another different value for the t interval
```

So, I wonder if I have an error in the concept or if I have an error using the R functions.

Comment: Your `f` model uses information about the x-values which the call to `t.test` does not. Hence it's not different computational methods but different models and that is why they give the different results. If you use `f <- lm(y ~ 1)` then you get the same results. In general when you compute the intervals for a linear regression type model you need to include the error in both the slope as well as the intercept and the `predict` function does that for you

Comment: Saul Why do you think those three things should be the same?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, some of your calculations use the x-values while other calculations do not.

So, reproducing your calculations for the confidence interval of y (irrespective of x), we have

```
data(mtcars)
y <- mtcars$mpg
n <- nrow(mtcars)

# METHOD 1
t.test(y)

# One Sample t-test
# 
# data:  y
# t = 18.857, df = 31, p-value < 2.2e-16
# alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#   17.91768 22.26357
# sample estimates:
#   mean of x 
# 20.09062 


# METHOD 2
mean(y) + c(-1, 1) * qt(p = 0.975, df = n - 1) * sqrt(var(y) / n)
# [1] 17.91768 22.26357

# METHOD 3
f <- lm(y ~ 1)
predict(f, interval = "confidence")
# fit      lwr      upr
# 1  20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 2  20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 3  20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 4  20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 5  20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 6  20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 7  20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 8  20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 9  20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 10 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 11 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 12 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 13 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 14 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 15 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 16 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 17 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 18 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 19 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 20 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 21 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 22 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 23 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 24 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 25 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 26 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 27 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 28 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 29 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 30 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 31 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
# 32 20.09062 17.91768 22.26357
```